# How to call an external function in redux

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, react-redux

is there anyway to call an external funtion or a function from a hook in redux slice ?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null,

  },
  reducers: {
    setCredentials(state, action) {
      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = action.payload;

      // I want to call an external funtion here

    },
  },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I want to call an external function or destruct a function from a hook and invoke it in setCredentials funtion in reducers

Comment: *What* is the external function you want to call? Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the code you want, or are trying, to use. If there are errors, include those details.

Comment: no matter what is external function I just want to now how I can import that function into that code above

Comment: You would import it just like any other import. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Not enough context but anyways dont forget hooks are used only to change state (so calling hook in another hook doesn't make sense). You can look at redux-saga library. Call saga function (based on generator function), then an external function and later your setCredentials hook.

Correct me, if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: do you mean redux  are used to only change state? or hooks? I guess hook are not just for changing states

Comment: "so calling hook in another hook doesn't make sense" ? Most hooks use other hooks inside of them.